# SonarQube C++ Community plugin UTF-8 with BOM parsing

Tags: c++, sonarqube-5.0

I am using sonarqube 5.0 + community C++ plugin.
And plugin fails on files whith UTF-8 with BOM encoding with this error:

```
[15:45:20][Step 1/19] 05:44:26.037 ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 0:
[15:45:20][Step 1/19]
[15:45:20][Step 1/19] --> ï»¿
[15:45:20][Step 1/19] 2:
[15:45:20][Step 1/19] 3:
[15:45:20][Step 1/19] 4: namespace Foo
```

Have anyone solving for this issue?